# Воспроизведение следующей/предыдущей песни при помощи сервиса через кнопки в уведомлении

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver, уведомления

Есть плеер, в котором как только выбираешь песню, создается уведомление, в котором есть 3 кнопки: включить предыдущую песню, следующую и пауза. Эти кнопки необходимы для того, чтобы приложением можно было пользоваться в фоновом режиме, управляя плеером через эти кнопки без открытия активности. Однако почему-то при нажатии на эти кнопки ничего не происходит. Вот код, где создаю обработчики для кнопок и само уведомление:

```
Intent intentPrev = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intentPrev.setAction(ACTION_PREV);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentPrev = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentPrev, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intentPlay = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intentPlay.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentPlay = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentPlay, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intentNext = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intentNext.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentNext = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentNext, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification).
                setContentTitle(songs.get(songPos).getTitle()).setContentText(songs.get(songPos).getArtist()).
                addAction(R.drawable.previous, "Previous", pendingIntentPrev).addAction(R.drawable.pause, "Pause", pendingIntentPlay).
                addAction(R.drawable.next, "Next", pendingIntentNext);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

А вот Receiver:

```
package asus.example.com.player;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.Objects;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String    ACTION_PREV = "PREVIOUS";
    private final String    ACTION_PLAY = "PLAY";
    private final String    ACTION_NEXT = "NEXT";
    private final MyService service     = new MyService();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), ACTION_PREV)){
            service.playPrev();
        }
        else if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), ACTION_NEXT)){
            service.playNext();
        }
    }
}
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Протестировал ваше приложение и нашел ошибку. Используйте

```
PendingIntent pendingIntentPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, intentPlay, 0);
```