# Почему BroadcastReceiver не принимает сообщения?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

Имеется часть кода, в которой создается интент:

```
Intent intentPrev = new Intent(this, ListOfSongsActivity.class);
        intentPrev.setAction(ACTION_PREV);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentPrev = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentPrev, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

В классе `ListOfSongsActivity` есть класс ресивера

```
private BroadcastReceiver NotificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("PREVIOUS")){
                playPrev();
            }
        }
    };
```

В методе `onCreate` этой активности регистрирую ресивер

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(NotificationReceiver, new IntentFilter("PREVIOUS"));
```

Однако, почему-то, когда в уведомлении нажимаю на кнопку и, по сути, ресивер должен получать интент, ничего не происходит. В чем ошибка?

**UPD**

Чуть дальше создаю еще один ресивер, и он без записи в манифесте нормально работает.

```
Intent onPreparedIntent = new Intent("MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(onPreparedIntent);

private BroadcastReceiver onPrepareReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            controller.show(0);
        }
    };
```

Так же регистрирую его, как и предыдущий:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onPrepareReceiver, new IntentFilter("MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED"));
```

Answer (score 3):

[Продолжение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/939605/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5/939797#939797).
Ресивер не нужно регистрировать, а просто указать в манифесте:

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver"/>
```

У меня все работает на Android 7.0.

Обращаю внимание, что начиная с Android 8, ваш код работать не будет.
Для создания уведомления нужно будет еще использовать [каналы](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-channels.html), а действия добавляются через [Notification.Action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Action).
Я это тоже протестировал на Android 8.1: работает.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ко мне есть вопросы?